# Javascript - Factorize a series of similar functions by passing name variable as parameter

Tags: javascript

I have a series of Timers that I need to reset at certain points of my app. The timers themselves are not present here are different so no need to factorize but the various functions to reset them are exactly the same, apart form the name of the timer to reset.

```
function resetMyFirstTimer() {
    if (window.myFirstTimer) {
      console.log("reset any potential prexisting myFirstTimer timer");
      clearTimeout(window.myFirstTimer);
    }
  }
function resetMySecondTimer() {
    if (window.mySecondTimer) {
      console.log("reset any potential prexisting mySecondTimer timer");
      clearTimeout(window.mySecondTimer);
    }
  }
function resetMyThirdTimer() {
    if (window.myThirdTimer) {
      console.log("reset any potential prexisting myThirdTimer timer");
      clearTimeout(window.myThirdTimer);
    }
  }
function resetMyFourthTimer() {
    if (window.myFourthTimer) {
      console.log("reset any potential prexisting myFourthTimer timer");
      clearTimeout(window.myFourthTimer);
    }
  }
and so on...
```

I created a function to create them once and call them then with this function:

```
function resetTimer(timerName) {
    if (window.timerName) {
      console.log("reset any potential prexisting " + timerName + " timer");
      clearTimeout(window.timerName);
    }
  }
```

My issue is then how to call them. This is not working. I would like to do:

```
resetTimer(myFirstimer);
resetTimer(mySecondtimer);
resetTimer(myThirdimer);
resetTimer(myFourthTimer);
```

- if I use

  resetTimer(myFirstimer);

I get myFirstTimer is not defined

- if I use

`resetTimer("myFirstimer")`;
I tested and alert(window.myFirstTimer) will send undefined

This is how for example I define myFirstTimer

```
window.myFirstTimer = setTimeout(showAlert, 10000);

function showAlert() {
//do stuff
}
```

So how to call them for different timer names?

Comment: Can you show us how you define the variables in question?

Comment: Sure will add it now on the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference global vars (window objects) using bracket notation.  Here's an example...

```js
function showVar(varName) {
    console.log(window[varName]);
}

window.someVar = "Hello there"; // create global var
showVar("someVar");             // reference global var by name
```

It's simple enough to implement in your scenario.  Change your function to this...

```
function resetTimer(timerName) {
    if (!window[timerName]) {
        console.log("reset any potential prexisting " + timerName + " timer");
        clearTimeout(window[timerName]);
    }
}

resetTimer("myFirstTimer");
```

However, you can just pass the timeout ID into the function.  This does mean you can't reference the timeout name as you previously did but makes more sense...

```
function resetTimer(timeoutId) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    // anything else you want to do when you cancel a timeout
}

resetTimer(window.myFirstTimer);
```

Comment: FYI, in a case variables are declared using `let` or `const`, this won't work.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks.  That's for Op's information, not mine.  I know that ;)

Comment: "FOP'sI" might be an infamous initialization = ). I just thought it might be good to mention in the answer. Anyway, `window.variable` is not declaration dependent, hence that would work in all cases ...

Comment: @Teemu No it's a fair point so I've asked the OP for more information.  This answer could just be 100% wrong, depending on their response.  I'll update or remove, depending on what they come back with.

Comment: I added the way I define myFirstTimer today , as it might indeed impact the answer.

Comment: based on your present suggestion, how do I call resetTimer? like this => resetTimer(myFirstTimer) or resetTimer("myFirstTimer") ? If Iunderstand right, it would be  resetTimer("myFirstTimer")

Comment: Yes, the name in quotes.  However, now you've updated the question you don't need to do that.  You can just pass the variable itself, unless you have a reason for wanting to pass the name as a string?

Comment: No, no reason, just being quite newbie in javascript. I'd prefer to do it the clean way, how can I pass "with variable itself"? As mentionned in the question, on the start, my attempts failed

Comment: I'll try without quotes then too

Comment: I've just updated the answer with both versions.  I do quite like the logging in the first method, so it's up to you really.  The second function is more "expected", but does nothing different really and has the same outcome.

Comment: I tried the ssecond suggestion with function resetTimer(timeoutId) {...it works but I fera it's not really working, i mean at the start of resetTimer(timeoutId) {. i have a check with if to make sure timer already exist: resetTimer(timeoutId) { if (timeoutId) //do this.... But I would have thought (timeoutId) which equals to window.myFirstTimer for example would be a boolean true/false but when I use a alert(timeoutId) inside function resetTimer(timeoutId) , it gives me not true or false but 1. Is it normal. How can window.myFirstTimer = 1?

Comment: A timeout ID is an integer value, not a boolean, so that's perfectly normal.  Also, unless you want to do something when the timeout doesn't exist, it's perfectly okay to execute `clearTimeout(timeoutId);`  It won't fail if it doesn't exist.

Comment: No problem - happy to help :)